# Android Chrome Remote Debugging Breakpoints ignored after WebSocket send

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova, websocket, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug an issue in a phoneGap based application that uses the WebView. I followed steps in

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

to setup debugging a webview. I am able to debug and and set breakpoints fine accept in the following scenario:

During a android chrome remote debugging session I set breakpoints in the javascript console. Initially my breakpoints are hit and the application pauses. However when my application sends data through a WebSocket my breakpoints pause for a moment but then proceed without me pressing continue. How can I get breakpoints to be honored during WebSocket communication?

Comment: Could the problem be that there is interference created by the WebSocket channel with the Debug channel?

Comment: The issue was that I was using a WebSocket library. When I removed the library and just used the native Websocket (supported in android  KitKat browsers) the issue went away. So the problem was with the WebSocket library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using a WebSocket library. When I removed the library and just used the native Websocket (supported in android KitKat browsers) the issue went away. So the problem was with the WebSocket library.